# Add text to placeholder in css

Tags: css, placeholder

```
<input type='text' />
```

I need to add placeholder text in css, something like this:

```
input:placeholder{content: 'placeholder text';}
```

Comment: You can't. You could use another elements as fake placeholder and position it over the `input` element if you really wanted to. If you want to modify the `placeholder` attribute, you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Why not use the `placeholder` attribute in the markup, like normal?

Comment: I need <input placeholder='input 1' /><input placeholder='input 2' />. User can delete inputs, so if user deletes first input, then with javascript need to change all other elements.

Comment: I can use label:after{} tu place fake placeholder over input, but how i can know that user have some value input?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set placeholders using CSS for all browsers. The only browser that supports it at the moment is webkit.

Take a look at this question: [How to set placeholder value using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075986/how-to-set-placeholder-value-using-css)

Comment: Not even that way. It wont allow to create the placeholder. It just allows you to change the placeholder text (once the input already have the placeholder attribute)

Answer (score 1):

you cant do this with css. however you can accomplish this with jQuery as shown in the demo below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    placeholders();
    function placeholders() {
        var count = 0;
        $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
            count++;
   $(this).attr('placeholder', 'value ' + count);
        });
    }
    
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
     $(this).closest('div').remove();
        placeholders();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text"/><button class="delete">DELETE</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text"/><button class="delete">DELETE</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text"/><button class="delete">DELETE</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text"/><button class="delete">DELETE</button>
</div>
```