# set placeholder fo external form

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, placeholder

One of my costumer wanted a landing page visible [HERE](http://site.resicert.com/a-landing-woo/). He wanted us to use wooform external service to achieve this form because it is already linked in their managing software. CSS is currently blocked because we need an ssl certificate to make them run properly. By the way you can view the result clicking on the shield in the right -top corner in chrome and loading the "unsafe script".

The problem is that wooform doesn't allowme to set placeholder but just default value. I want to display a placeholder and I'm trying to do that in javascript by this way:

```
document.getElementById("Field1").placeholder = "Type name here..";
```

Unfortunately it is not working and I think it depends on  the delay wooform is loaded with. So I tried to do this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$.getScript("http://site.resicert.com/placeholder.js", function(){
   alert("Script loaded and executed.");
 });
</script>
```

But still no luck...

What can I do? I'm newbie in Javascript... 
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the `noConflict()` mode. This is to prevent compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress can utilize.

The way to make your second code block work would be to change it to the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.getScript("http://site.resicert.com/placeholder.js", function(){
       alert("Script loaded and executed.");
    });
});
</script>
```

**Update:** 
Try the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>   
jQuery.getScript("http://site.resicert.com/placeholder.js", function(){
  alert("Script loaded and executed.");
});
</script>
```

Comment: I offered an updated solution, but I doubt it will make a difference. What does your JS console output?

Comment: still not working.. console outputs a lot of errors but I think they come from wooform...

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075986/how-to-set-placeholder-value-using-css but I did some test and it works just if I have an empty tag placeholder in my input. :'(

Comment: I would recommend contacting Wufoo support and seeing if they have a solution, because it seems you're spinning your wheels on this.

Comment: Ok, I will try to contact them. Thanks for your help so far!