# Changing Placeholder value in HTML input

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change a placeholder in an html input (a text shown when no text is yet typed in the input field). Unfortunately, I don't have access to change the HTML file so I can't change it there. I only have access to the CSS file. Is there a way to change or hide the current placeholder text? It looks like this in HTML:

```
placeholder="example"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set placeholder value using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075986/how-to-set-placeholder-value-using-css)

Comment: in CSS you could set the placeholder color to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the value of the `HTML` using `CSS`, you can only style the `HTML` using `CSS`. Hence the name, "Cascading Style Sheets".

So the answer to your questions is that it is impossible to change the `placeholder` value using css.

However if you have access to JavaScript, you would be able to change the `value` of the `placeholder` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Like our friend koder613 said, you can easily achieve this with `javascript`.
The code is posted, and I'm sorry if your code doesn't have access to `js`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

First Name: <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Name">

<p>Click the button to change the placeholder text of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myText").placeholder = "Type name here..";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```