# Change text that is place holder in html via CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following info on a web site that I can not edit the html, but I can edit the CSS.

```
<textarea id="gui-form-comment" name="comment" placeholder="Comment" style="width:100%;" data-validate-before-update="false"></textarea>
```

I want to change the placeholder to something else.

Comment: This is not possible in CSS since this is HTML Content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set placeholder value using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075986/how-to-set-placeholder-value-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is not possible, but you can mimick the behaviour in modern browsers. But you need a selector for the parent element of the textarea and you may need to tweak the font, size and position of the `#container::before` pseudo-placeholder to match the formatting of your textarea.

```css
/* Hide real placeholder */
#container textarea::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

/* Add pseudo-placeholder */
#container::before {
    content: 'New placeholder';
    position: absolute;
    font-family: monospace;
    padding: 4px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* Show and hide the pseudo-placeholder */
#container textarea {
    position: relative;
}
#container textarea:placeholder-shown {
    position: static;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <textarea id="gui-form-comment" name="comment" placeholder="Comment" style="width:100%;" data-validate-before-update="false"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

So if you can specify the height to the textarea then it'd be easy to make it happened:

```
<textarea
  id="gui-form-comment"
  name="comment"
  placeholder="Comment"
  style="width: 100%; height: 100px;"
  data-validate-before-update="false"
></textarea>
<style>
  #gui-form-comment::placeholder {
    line-height: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

The ::placeholder is actually safe to use (https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3Aplaceholder)